# 4-player arena game networking model : dedicated servers?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, game-state

So my question is not technically limited to 4-player games, but there has been a lot of games on steam lately (brawlhalla, duck game etc) that seem to be quite popular lately.

My question is, are these games hosted on a separate server, or do one player host the game, and the game developers just providing a match-making service?

If it's hosted by one of the player, how do they get around with NAT issues? If hosted by some server somewhere - that sounds like it's super expensive to run?

Also, for these games, what kind of networking model is "standard"? Are there any articles about this I can read?

Comment: That's why you normally determine in your application the NAT of the user. Then you can say who is able to host and who not. Next if you choose such a system,  a competitive game is not possible as cheaters will have direct access to the server data send from the clients. So it's only valiable for non competitive games like coop. And yes if you choose thus approach it's typically the game distributor that hosts a matchmaking server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no golden bullet "this is how you do it" type answer to this other than to say, generally speaking you have 2 options TCP or UDP.

Given the fact that you are only ever dealing with 4 players TCP might be a better choice as you get some additional protocol level checks that help ensure reliable networking.

Net up is for you to decide how you want your game to work.

If you want to have dedicated servers then do that, if you want users to be able to setup and host their own games do that, we can't tell you how to design your game.

That said some form of async socket on both the server and clients will likely be the way you go so I would start there by getting 2 console apps to talk to each other then look at how to implement that in your game.

**EDIT**

That said unless you are building your own game engine it's likely that the engine you are using has some options for this that you may want to consider.

And you may wish to consider things like ...

- TCP is more resource intensive (on server not net) compared to UDP.
- There is UDP hole punching if you want to let players behind nat host the game.

Comment: I think you should also add two other details to your answer:
1. TCP is way more resource intensive (on server not net) compared to UDP.
2. There is [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) if you want to let players behind nat host the game.

Comment: good call, those are neat features